# why the list is value is 'None' when same variable is assigned to it? Please check the code given

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
l = [5,4,3,2,1]
l = l.sort()
print(l) << this prints "None"  << why is this happening

l = [5,4,3,2,1]
k = l.sort()
print(k) << this prints "None"
print(l) << This prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

May I know what's the exact behaviour?

Comment: `sort` changes the list in-place.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of that `sort` method, sort the list in-place and when you assign it to any variable it would be `None`.

If you want to assign the result of your sort you can use `sorted` instead of `sort`.

```
>>> l = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> l = sorted(l)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```